# Do functional algorithms require more memory than imperative algorithms?

Tags: functional-programming, performance, programming-paradigms, imperative-programming

Let's suppose we are counting words in string. We split it so what we have is an array of strings. I'll use Python as an example.

The imperative approach would as follows:

```
wordcount = {}
for word in words:
    wordcount[word] += 1
```

The functional would be:

```
uniquewords = set(words)
wordcount = [words.count(w) for w in words]
```

For each word w we are doing a full scan on the words array, while the imperative approach goes over each word just once. Am I right to suppose that the functional way of doing it will consume a lot more resources than the imperative one?

Comment: The functional one only does one pass of the array as well. What resources it uses depends on the back-end implementation - it may look no different in machine code to the imperative approach.

Comment: I don't think it is fair to compare functional approaches to imperative ones, by using different algorithms with different asymptotical time complexities (one is $O(n^2)$, and the other is $O(n)$).

Comment: They is no reason to assume that smart compilers can output very similar machine code for either paradigm. You'll have to dig a little deeper and make assumptions resp. impose restrictions on the functional compiler.

Comment: What do you mean by "functional algorithms"? It sounds like you're asking if the implementation of an algorithm expressed functionally requires more memory than the implementation of the same algorithm expressed imperatively. But that depends entirely on the quality of the two implementations (i.e., compilers). Could you clarify your question?

Comment: Also, your "functional" example doesn't look at all functional to me.

Comment: Rodrigo, if you want to ask a new question, ask it as a new question. Don't edit questions to completely change their meaning after they've already been answered.

Comment: @Raphael Though not very good in itself, this question has a good answer. It should be edited, rather than put on hold, at the risk of deletion.

Comment: @babou You'll note that I was not part of the closing decision (for once :D), so you may want to talk to other people.

Comment: @raphael I noticed that, but I do not know how to communicate well in that situation. I wanted to comment the question, not in chat, and preferably a moderator. I wish I could attach a note when voting for reopen (or for/against close) to explain why, so that other voters would see it.

Comment: Guys, sorry for the problems, I'll post this question again as according to @babou it might have a good answer.

Answer (score 7):

Your example of "functional programming" is a pretty poor one. For starters, it is not functional because it uses state (it stores something in `words` and behind the scenes `set(words)` is doing stateful stuff as well). To actually learn what functional programming is about, you should look outside an imperative language such as Python. Python often uses imperative features dressed up as functional programming. Have a look at Ocaml or Haskell.

As for your question, people have thought about just how efficiently one can implement functional programs on standard hardware (which I think is what you're asking). At LICS 2015 the following paper has been accepted:

> B. Accattoli, C. Sacerdoti Coen. [On the Relative Usefulness of Fireballs](https://sites.google.com/site/beniaminoaccattoli/Accattoli%2C%20Sacerdoti%20Coen%20-%20On%20the%20Usefulness%20of%20Fireballs.pdf?attredirects=0). LICS 2015.

In it the authors show that a RAM machine (standard hardware) can simulate $\lambda$-calculus (functional programming) with a linear-time overhead with respect to the number of computation steps ($\beta$-reductions) of the functional program. This shows that functional programs can be efficiently implemented on existing hardware and will *not* in general consume a lot more resources.

Let me also point out that you cannot make the comparison you're trying to make in a sensible way. You are comparing two *different* algorithms that compute the same function. Instead, you should be comparing two *implementations* of the same algorithm in an imperative and a functional style. For instance sorting algorithms would do. And you should use a language that supports both imperative and functional programming. For instance, we could take merge sort and use the [rosettacode.org](http://rosettacode.org) functional implementation of [merge srot in OCaml](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Merge_sort#OCaml). Perhaps someone has the time to play with this and post some comparisons.